# Is it possible to use StreamWriter methods to append text to the file that was created with the File.AppendAllText() Method?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

Is there a known problem for the StreamWriter's methods to deal with the files, that were created with File.AppendAllText method?

```
public void WriteLog(string msg){
        
        if (msg != string.Empty){
            
            string logFileName = "Protokoll.txt";
            using (StreamWriter logWriter = new StreamWriter(logFileName, true)){
                
                logWriter.WriteLine(msg);
            }
        }
}
```

[vs, console, directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VqQ3.png)

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem. The Protokoll.txt file seems to be responsive (assuming from the last access date) but wont add any new lines. Although it is possible to open it with editor and write manually into it. Other txt files get along without any problems. The WriteLog is a part of a Server-Client School Project. It uses NetworkStream and is called from the ReceiveMessages method. Interesting hint about file location moving during code execution, @mjwills

Comment: `File.AppendAllText()` is `StreamWriter(filePath, true, encoding).Write([string content])`, where `true` of course means *append to the file*.

Comment: What exact issue are you having? @Jimi with relevant `using` blocks of course

Comment: Are you experiencing a problem? If so, describe it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. File1 is created with static File.AppendAllText() and File2 with the Method from StreamWriter (above). After running WriteLog again in File1 appear no new lines, in File2 appending new line works just fine. The only difference between these two files is the way there were created.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. I'd also suggest your path not be just a filename, since your code as is will act strangely if the working directory changes during program execution.

Comment: Also note, don't write your own logger, use someone else's

Comment: @TheGeneral, this appears to be for academic purposes.